# Multiparameter / ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

I have a Ruby application that allows a user to search. I am building a data storage table that saves every search that happens on the site. In the creation, I pass in a few things:

`ID of returned object`
`controller action`
`Search term`
`ip address of user`
`additional filters`

Of these 5 items, 4 are singular and work just fine, however, `additional filters` is plural saves as a weird escaped string. If I sent simply save the filters, it looks something like this:

```
"---\n- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess\n  type: city\n  value: San Francisco\n- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess\n  type: sport\n  value: Basketball\n- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess\n  type: sport\n  value: Football\n"
```

This is the output of these filters:
`[{"type"=>"city", "value"=>"San Francisco"}, {"type"=>"sport", "value"=>"Basketball"}, {"type"=>"sport", "value"=>"Football"}]`

I've tried a lot of methods, but I can't really clean it up the way I want to. How can I either avoid `HashWithIndifferentAccess` or adjust for the result.

SCHEMA:

```
create_table "search_counts", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "search_countable_id"
    t.string   "search_countable_type"
    t.integer  "search_returns"
    t.datetime "created_at",            :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",            :null => false
  end

 create_table "search_count_details", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "search_count_id"
    t.string   "ip_address",      :limit => 15
    t.datetime "created_at",                    :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                    :null => false
    t.string   "action"
    t.string   "query"
    t.text     "filters"
 end
```

Comment: Whar's your model code for this? Should be some kind of `serialize` I guess. What's the controller? Do you just directly store the params hash there? Since that's a HashWithIndifferentAccess you may have to map it to a normal Hash.

Comment: No, what do I need to serialize? I just have a "has_many search counts" in the model. and a find or create by in the search count model. what do I serialize?

Comment: This looks like you try to store that hash with the filter output to a string. If you store hashes it's better to serialize them.

Comment: How do I serialize the hash? I posted the schema.